# MVC 4 Passing a model from a view to a generic method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, generics, parameter-passing

I am trying to create an export-to-excel button on various intranet reporting pages which takes in a generic viewmodel. I would like to access this method from any view within my application but for now I'm attempting it from a single controller.
(NOTE: The viewmodel must be passed from the view because the viewmodel is filtered by the user)

My method in my controller is as follows:

```
public void ExportToExcel<T>(T model, string fileName)
        {
            GridView gv = new GridView();
            var lst = (IEnumerable<T>)model;
            gv.DataSource = lst.ToList();
            gv.DataBind();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ".xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
            Response.Charset = "";
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            gv.RenderControl(htw);
            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
            Response.Clear();
        }
```

And I'm calling it using:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ExportToExcel", new { model = (IEnumerable< Reporting.Models.HelplineSalesViewModel >) Model, fileName = "HelplineSales" })">Export to Excel</a>
```

When clicked I get the error :

> "Cannot call action method 'Void ExportToExcel[T](T, System.String)' on controller 'Reporting.Controllers.PostersController' because the action method is a generic method.
>   Parameter name: methodInfo "

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot call action method 'System.Web.Mvc.PartialViewResult Foo\[T\](T)' on controller 'Controller' because the action method is a generic method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870116/cannot-call-action-method-system-web-mvc-partialviewresult-foott-on-contro)

Comment: Your error says that you can't have a generic Action method in your controller. What you'll need to do is set up separate typed Action methods for each type of object you want to export to Excel. Then call this generic method from each of them.

Comment: Had you tried linqToCsv as its quite generic and fast to create CSV from any model with lots of other functionality like custom column headers, date formats and also controls ordering. have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library So once you have the model in Controller method then you can create CSV from that easily...

Comment: Cheers for the replies, had a problem with the viewmodel being empty when passed through to the method but seems to be sorted now, thanks @krillgar !!

Comment: @Grantard: Please post your last comment as an answer and accept it when you can. Otherwise, the question remains in the unanswered list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Your error says that you can't have a generic Action method in your controller. What you'll need to do is set up separate typed Action methods for each type of object you want to export to Excel. Then call this generic method from each of them." – krillgar